# Sqlite3: Store db table names in a vector

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

**Note: c++98**

I'm trying to retrieve the table names inside a database and store them inside a vector as strings.

My code:

```c++
typedef vector<string> dbTableTypes;

static int callback1(void *handle, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    // FILE *f1 = (FILE *)handle;
    dbTableTypes *dbTables = (dbTableTypes*)handle;
    int i;
    char *pEnd;
    const char *sep = "\t";

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int Database::dbTableNames()
{
    static string sqlGetTableNames = "select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';";
    vector<string> dbTables;
    char* err_msg(NULL);
    int rc(SQLITE_ERROR);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlGetTableNames.c_str(), callback1, &dbTables, &err_msg);
}
```

I can print the table names within the callback, but it's not being reflected in the `dbTableNames` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Solution for the curious:

```c++
typedef vector<string> dbTableTypes;

static int callback1(void *handle, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    dbTableTypes *dbTables = (dbTableTypes*)handle;
    int i;
    char *pEnd;
    const char *sep = "\t";

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
        dbTables->push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int Database::dbTableNames()
{
    static string sqlGetTableNames = "select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';";
    vector<string> dbTables;
    char* err_msg(NULL);
    int rc(SQLITE_ERROR);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlGetTableNames.c_str(), callback1, &dbTables, &err_msg);

    for(int i = 0; i < dbTables.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Tables: " << dbTables[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```